# Rightclicking on Div (infobox) is Disabled. How do I enable it

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps

I am using the Infobox plugin for Google Maps V3 API. http://google-maps-utility-library-v3.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/infobox/docs/reference.html

**Problem:** When I rightclick on the infobox div, nothing happens. Same goes for any div that is the child of the parent infobox div. However I have an input box that contains some text that I want to be able to select and rightclick copy.

How can this be done if I cannot rightclick on it? More importantly, how can I enable right clicking?

**Example**

http://google-maps-utility-library-v3.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/infobox/examples/infobox-basic.html

---

**JS Code** *Does not work*

```
var infoboxOptions = {
    content: boxText,
    disableAutoPan: true,
    maxWidth: 0,
    pixelOffset: new google.maps.Size(0, 0),
    zIndex: null,
    infoBoxClearance: new google.maps.Size(5, 5),
    closeBoxURL: '',
    isHidden: true,
    pane: "floatPane",
    enableEventPropagation: false,
    contextmenu: true
    };
```

Answer (score 7):

I modifed the infobox.js code to get it working.

Changed this:

```
    this.contextListener_ = google.maps.event.addDomListener(this.div_, "contextmenu", ignoreHandler);
```

to this:

```
    this.contextListener_ = google.maps.event.addDomListener(this.div_, "contextmenu", cancelHandler);
```

DISCLAIMER: this may have other ill effects I am not aware of as I didn't test it thoroughly, but it works in my case.

Comment: and then used an [online version of uglifyjs](http://marijnhaverbeke.nl/uglifyjs) to minify the code.

Answer (score 1):

Just add "contextmenu: true" to the set of options

Comment: I edited the original post to show the code with `contextmenu:true` that does not enable the rightclick

Answer (score 1):

I pulled this from the infobox.js source:

> - @property {boolean} enableEventPropagation Propagate mousedown, click, dblclick,
> - and contextmenu events in the InfoBox (default is false to mimic the behavior
> - of a google.maps.InfoWindow). Set this property to true if the InfoBox
> - is being used as a map label. iPhone note: This property setting has no effect; events are
> - always propagated.

Looks like setting your enableEventPropagation property to true should do the trick!

Answer (score -1):

Try this code. This is very short code and very useful code. And this is Javascript not jQuery so it will work for all browsers.

To disable right click

```js
function yourFunction() {
  alert("Not allowed");
}

document.oncontextmenu = new Function("yourFunction();return false;");
```

To Renable Right Click

```js
document.oncontextmenu = new Function("return true;");
```