# Right click in an infobox doesn't work

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3

I have the exact **same problem** as in this post :

[Rightclicking on Div (infobox) is Disabled. How do I enable it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8633279/rightclicking-on-div-infobox-is-disabled-how-do-i-enable-it)

I use **Chrome** and **Google map api** and I would like to "inspect element" by right clicking onto it but it doest work.
The solution proposed in the other post doesn't work.

Do you have an idea why ?

Edit : Add some code.

```
var boxText = document.createElement("div");
boxText.id = "infoBoxDiv";
boxText.style.cssText = "margin: 0px;";

var myOptions = {
        content : boxText
        ,disableAutoPan: false
        ,maxWidth: 0
        ,pixelOffset: new google.maps.Size(0, 0)
        ,zIndex: null

        ,boxStyle: { 
            margin : "0px",
            padding : "0px",
            border : "none",
          opacity: 1
          ,width: "420px"
         }
        ,closeBoxMargin: "0px 0px 0px 0px"
        ,closeBoxURL: ""
        ,infoBoxClearance: new google.maps.Size(1, 1)
        ,isHidden: false
        ,pane: "floatPane"
        ,enableEventPropagation: false
};
infowindow = new InfoBox(myOptions);
```

And I use : 
    infowindow.setContent(stringContent);
to set the content.

You have the exact same problem here : http://google-maps-utility-library-v3.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/infobox/examples/infobox-basic.html

Comment: In the code you posted above you're not actually using the solution provided in your link. Also FWIW, if you just want to be able to bring up the element inspector in Chrome, you can also use the Command-Shift-C keyboard shortcut.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The question that you referred has the answer there listed as well:

```
var infoboxOptions = {
    content: boxText,
    disableAutoPan: true,
    maxWidth: 0,
    pixelOffset: new google.maps.Size(0, 0),
    zIndex: null,
    infoBoxClearance: new google.maps.Size(5, 5),
    closeBoxURL: '',
    isHidden: true,
    pane: "floatPane",
    enableEventPropagation: false,
    contextmenu: true
    };
```

You need to set `contextmenu: true` to get it working.

**UPDATE**

Try adding the following event.

```
google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'click', function(e) {
                contextmenu:true
            });
```

**2nd UPDATE**

The problem lies within the Infobox.js file that you have included. In this File the right click or the contextmenu has been prevented by default.

If you take a look at a normal Google Maps InfoWindow, it works as exoected and you need not to add any additional code for that. take a look at my below DEMO with Infowindow and right click working as expected;

[**RIGHT CLICK ON AN INFOWINDOW DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/refhat/XW35W/2/)

Comment: Hello,

In fact,the infowindow works but is not customisable ...
In fact, my problem is not really to "inspect the element" but :
I have a div with some text in my infobox and because the text is large, and the div is fixed, there is a scrollbar. But when I scroll with the mouse, it's scrolling the map and my div ... That's my problem right now .

Comment: I doubt you can do anything with that. If you want to scroll the infowindow, you need to have focus on that otherwise your maps window will scroll

Comment: I was able to do it by disabling the scroll on google map when hovering my element.